# Что такое экспонента числа?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

При чтении чужого кода столкнулся с функцией **exp**. В справочнике написано что эта функция вычисляет **экспоненту числа**. Подскажите что это такое?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Экспонента](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0) - функция, где число Эйлера `e` (e≈2,718) возводится в степень аргумента `x`. Данная функция применяется в огромном количестве математических выкладок. Обратной функцией к экспоненте является натуральный логарифм.